# Is it considered a bad-practice to select distinct elements by catching their class/id in a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

I've been using Jquery for some time now and I have a question concerning bad/good practices. Here is the deal. Lets say we have this HTML:

```
 <span class="а_s_trigger" id="tekst1">text1</span>
 <span class="а_s_trigger" id="video1">video1</span>
                <div class="a_s_songvideo" id="showvideo1">

                        <object>
                           //video1
                        </object>

                </div>
                <div class="a_s_songtext" id="showtext1">

                        <p>
                        //text1
                        </p>

                </div>
```

And the following jQuery function that triggers hide/show on click for an element that is either video or text.

```
$('.а_s_trigger')
           .bind('mouseover',function(e) {
                $(this).css({background:'#F3F3F3',cursor:'pointer'});
            })
            .bind('mouseout',function(e) {
                $(this).css({background:'#E6E6E6'});    
            })
            .bind('click',function(e) {
                var id=$(this).attr('id');
                var status=$(this).attr('id').toString().slice(0,5);
                var index=$(this).attr('id').toString().slice(5,7);
                var visibility=$('#showtext'+index).css('display');

                    if(status=='tekst1')
                    {
                        if(visibility=='block')
                        {
                            $('#showtext'+index).slideUp();
                        }
                        else if(visibility=='none')
                        {
                            $('#showtext'+index).slideDown();
                        }

                    }
                    else if(status=="video")
                    {
                        $('#showvideo'+index).toggle();
                    }




            });
```

Everything is working fine but what bugs me is the way I select the element I need :

```
var id=this.id;
var status=$(this).attr('id').toString().slice(0,5);
var index=$(this).attr('id').toString().slice(5,7);
var visibility=$('#showtext'+index).css('display');
```

Is it OK to assign variables to strings in such manner?
I know that jQuery is all about selectors and the nice chaining functions like :

```
$(this).children().siblings().attr('id'); //and so on
```

Should I always try to select elements using the chain selectors or should I follow the principle "If it works don't change it!"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm **a Class man**

```
 $(".button").  //etc
```

To me its much easier and you can grab multiple elements, but if you have no problem with your way as you said

> If it works don't change it!"

Comment: not only are classes easier, but the fact you can use more than one class on an element makes this the best solution.

Comment: I disagree with the "If it works don't change it" statement, if you can refactor some code to make it cleaner and more readable you have improved it. I consider unreadable code to be broken anyway.

Comment: @Miquel- if you're the only one to see or use the code then what works for you, works for you, now if a team is involved then that matters

Answer (score 2):

I think conditionals make your code a bit cluttered and difficult to read. In my opinion you could encapsulate the status within the event handlers.

Add the status as classes to your elements.

```
<span class="а_s_trigger tekst" id="t_001">text1</span>
<span class="а_s_trigger video" id="v_001">video1</span>
```

Bind accordingly:

```
$('.а_s_trigger').bind('mouseover',function(e) {
                        $(this).css({background:'#F3F3F3',cursor:'pointer'});
                }).bind('mouseout',function(e) {
                        $(this).css({background:'#E6E6E6'});
                });

$('.а_s_trigger .tekst').bind('click',function(e) {
    var index=this.id.toString().slice(2,6);
    var $element = $('#showtext'+index);
    var visibility=$element.css('display');
    if(visibility=='block')
    {
        $element.slideUp();
    }
    else
    {
        $element.slideDown();
    }});

$('.а_s_trigger .video').bind('click',function(e) {
    var index=this.id.toString().slice(2,6);
    $('#showvideo'+index).toggle;
});
```

EDIT:

The text handler could be substituted by (with a tiny performance penalty):

```
$('.а_s_trigger .tekst').bind('click',function(e) {
    var index=this.id.toString().slice(2,6);
    $('#showtext'+index + ':visible').slideUp();
    $('#showtext'+index + ':hidden').slideDown();
});
```

Comment: +1 for the advice. It's always good to view a workaround on a problem developed by others.

Comment: Only thing I would say is do a substring on a test for the underscore (this.id.toString().substring(this.id.toString().lastIndexOf('_')+1)). I like using something to separate values in a string, if that's the reason i'm using it.

Comment: I also think this is clearer, actually that is the reason I changed the id to be t_NUM but then used the original method ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's fine.  Since you're using the values multiple times in your conditional login, it makes sense to store them to a local variable first.

Random note: if you just need the id, this.id works just as well as $(this).attr('id').

Comment: You are right about the id. I sometimes forget that jQuery is actually JavaScript.